# Check if Socket is connected on physical machine

Tags: c#, sockets

Preface:

I have an asynchronous socket server where we receive telemetry data, and when the remote devices do not send us data, we have the ability to send commands to request data.  The listener and command processing are done on separate threads.  The listener listens on one port, while the commands send on a different port.

My overall question is: Is it possible with C# to check if a socket is connected without having to call a "connect" method in the first place?  Our customers device will establish a connection to the server and will remain connected always (unless service coverage drops or battery drains etc.).  I'd like to avoid having to keep track of all the connected socket objects in memory if possible.

To be honest I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is feasible.  I'd like to hear people's thoughts.

Comment: It is often necessary to have keepalive traffic sent periodically if you want to know that a connection is established and functioning, i.e. the system at the far end is responding.  The [Socket.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected(v=vs.100).aspx) property provides a much lower standard of connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the socket information, you could probably invoke [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get the state of the socket ("established" or not).

For an example of pinvoking this function, see:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/5b8eccd3-4db5-44a1-be29-534ed34a588d/

Comment: That is an awesome example and it should work perfectly for what I need.  Thank you very much!